# How to DRY up these routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way to DRY up these routes. There is a pattern to them:

```
get "articles/new" => "articles#new", :as => :new_article
post "articles/new" => "articles#create", :as => :create_article
get "articles/:slug/edit" => "articles#edit", :as => :edit_article

get "stores/:id/articles/new" => "articles#new", :as => :new_store_article, :defaults => { :scope => 'store' }
post "stores/:id/articles/new" => "articles#create", :as => :create_store_article, :defaults => { :scope => 'store' }
get "stores/:id/articles/:slug/edit" => "articles#edit", :as => :edit_store_article, :defaults => { :scope => 'store' }

get "warehouses/:id/articles/new" => "articles#new", :as => :new_warehouse_article, :defaults => { :scope => 'warehouse' }
post "warehouses/:id/articles/new" => "articles#create", :as => :create_warehouse_article, :defaults => { :scope => 'warehouse' }
get "warehouses/:id/articles/:slug/edit" => "articles#edit", :as => :edit_warehouse_article, :defaults => { :scope => 'warehouse' }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted an elegant solution and I seem to have found one. Basically, adding a helper method that I can use in my routes file by putting this in `lib/routes_helper.rb`:

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper
  def article_resources_for(scope = nil)
    scope_path_symbol = scope_path = nil
    defaults = {}

    unless scope.blank?
      scope_path = "#{scope}/:id/"
      scope_path_symbol = "#{scope}_"
      defaults = { :defaults => { :scope => scope } }

    get "#{scope_path}articles/new" => "articles#new", { :as => :"new_#{scope_path_symbol}article" }.merge(defaults)
    post "#{scope_path}articles/new" => "articles#create", { :as => :"create_#{scope_path_symbol}article" }.merge(defaults)
    get "#{scope_path}articles/:slug/edit" => "articles#edit", { :as => :"edit_#{scope_path_symbol}article" }.merge(defaults)

  end
end
```

Then in my `routes.rb` file, I can simply just do

```
article_resources_for
article_resources_for "stores"
article_resources_for "warehouses"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the slug in your articles different than article_id?  Try adding the below to your article model:

```
#This overrides the :id in your routes, and uses the slug instead
def to_param
  slug
end
```

Then, the following should work in your routes.

```
resources :articles, :only => [:new, :create, :edit]
scope :stores do
  resources :articles, :only => [:new, :create, :edit]
end
scope :warehouses
  resources :articles, :only => [:new, :create, :edit]
end
```

I highly recommend reading through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: What if I don't want to use resources (I plan on adding many different actions other than RESTful ones)? And how would I address the default params issue `:defaults => { :scope => '...' }`